# Automatically delete unnecessary files in an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, github, git-fork

I forked a repository from Github that has a lot of packages and files, implementing all kind of algorithms, simulations and utility classes.

However, in my research I don't need all of these files/packages for my own simulation to work.

I would like to keep my forked project as minimal as possible, so I would like to keep only the necessary packages/files that are needed to compile my simulation.

I'm talking specifically about the IDE Eclipse. If I decide to "backtrack" all imports starting from my simulation file, I would definitely get lost because the original project is big.

On the other side, if I decide to "delete" a package and see if my simulation compiles, I would stay all week trying this out, and if I delete a needed file I would have to attach it again to my project which is troublesome.

Is there an automatic tool I can use to do this on Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use a coverage checker to see what methods in what classes are used during execution, and delete the rest. And then revert anything that causes a compilation error.

This only works for code, not resources, though - and only if something like reflection isn’t used.